# Hebrews 6:2 and the Greek understanding of "Eternal Judgement"

Tags: hebrews, historical-interpretation

> "Therefore, leaving the discussion of the elementary principles of
> Christ, let us go on to perfection, not laying again the foundation of
> repentance from dead works and of faith toward God,
> of baptisms, of laying on of hands, of resurrection of the dead, and
> of **eternal judgment**.   And this we will do if God permits."

I have a few questions regarding the Greek text of Hebrews 6:2 in relation to the words of **eternal judgment**.

**1.)** Do the words "eternal judgment" imply an unending sequence of judgment that will never end? (**example:** (*The judgement will not cease upon the ungodly*)

**2.)** Do the words "eternal judgment" imply a sentencing that is "eternal" in nature or effect.  (**example**: *the judgment had eternal consequences*)

**3.)** If the author of Hebrews wanted to use words to describe an alternative view to continuous judgement, what would they use in Greek terms instead?   **example:***Ages, eternal pronunciation, eternal proclamation, eternal condemnation*  <-- I am not implying that these are alternative certainties, but alternative possibilities if the author of Hebrews was trying to convey anything BUT that which is already written.  (Hypothetical Scenario)

Comment: @Rajesh If you feel the need to answer this question, please answer it in the traditional sense.  :)

Comment: Ok, good idea. :)

Comment: @Rajesh I edited question 1 for better clarification in the "Example".

Comment: What was the purpose of adding that?

Comment: @Rajesh That’s what I meant all along, but I had to clarify it since points 1 & 2 seemed too identical.  
I meant from point 1: “unending judgment upon the ungodly”.  From point 2: “an eternal effect by which the consequences are forever without reference to the ungodly existing in consciousness.”  Of course I believe in “the second death” by which sinners do consciously get punished in Hell (Matthew 25:31-46).

Comment: Does "example" mean just that, an example. Or is it part of the question itself? Are you asking "Do the words "eternal judgment" imply a sentencing that is "eternal" in nature or effect?" Or are you asking, "Do the words "eternal judgment" imply a sentencing that is "eternal" in nature or effect, and does that imply hellfire?"

Comment: @Rajesh I could re-edit the example in example 1, but before I would consider that.  I’m talking about 2 different types of eternal effects here.  
Point 1 implies that those affected by judgment are in a state of eternal judgment.  Point 2 implies that the effects of judgment are of eternal consequence in terms of being annihilated or purified as opposed to being judged eternally.  (I still hold to the traditional doctrine of eternal conscious punishment).  I’m confused of this text in Hebrews 6:2 tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Heb 6:1, 2, the author of Hebrews lists six very basic Christian doctrines:

1. repentance from dead works
2. faith in God
3. instruction about baptisms/cleansing rites
4. laying on of hands
5. resurrection of the dead
6. eternal judgement

Note that the author does not define these and does not elaborate on any of them; therefore, from this passage we can say nothing about them other than they are basic Christian teachings.

To make the matter even more frustrating, Heb 6:2 is the only place where the phrase, "eternal judgement" occurs, so we cannot even examine other Scripture to discover its meaning.

All that can be said here is about the meaning of the word, κρίμα (krima) translated "judgement".  Actually, there are four nouns that are translated "judgement" and these provide the clue to answer the question.

**1. κρίμα (krima)** = verdict, sentence, or condemnation.  That is, a decision following the trial/investigation (#3 below), eg, Matt 7:2, 23:14, Mark 12:40, heb 6:2, etc.

**2. κατάκριμα (katakrima)** = a strengthened form of #1 and means "condemnation", eg, Rom 5:16, 18, 8:1.

**3. κρίσις (krisis)** = the process of making a decision, ie, a trial or investigation following an accusation, eg, Matt 5:21, 22, 10:15, 11:22, etc.

**4. κατάκρισις (katakrisis)** = a strengthened form of #3 above meaning condemnation, censure, 2 Cor 3:9, 7:3.

Back to Heb 6:2.  Since the word used in Heb 6:2 is κρίμα (krima) (#1 above), then we have a sentence or verdict which has the effect of either pronouncing the result of the judgement of people either for eternal life (1 John 5:11, John 3:36, 6:54, 10:28), or, eternal death (2 Thess 1:8-10, Heb 10:26, 27, 9:27).

Thus, God's decision is final and its effects eternal.

Comment: Well informed answer Dottard, thank you.  Eternal Verdict, that’s a heavy pill to swallow.  Noted.