# Is Hebrews 6:2 on the words "eternal judgement" in the Imperfect Aspect, Perfective Aspect, or Aoristic Aspect?

Tags: greek, grammar

I am aware of my other question here: [Hebrews 6:2 and the Greek understanding of "Eternal Judgement"](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/73643/hebrews-62-and-the-greek-understanding-of-eternal-judgement)

Yet, I am still desiring to know more of the **Greek structure of Hebrews 6:2** on the words "***Eternal Judgment***",

**Q**: **is "eternal Judgment" in the Imperfect Aspect, Perfective Aspect, or Aoristic Aspect?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Greek, "eternal judgement" is a phrase, κρίματος αἰωνίου ("judgement eternal" = noun + adjective) with the following grammar:

- "judgement" κρίματος = noun, genitive neuter singular
- "eternal" αἰωνίου = adjective, genitive neuter singular

Thus, because these words are NOT verbs, they cannot be imperfect or aorist, etc.  In fact, Heb 6:2 is a verse that contains no verbs at all.  This is because Heb 6:2 is part of a sentence begun in the previous verse which I would translate and analyze as follows:

> Heb 6:1, 2 Therefore, **having left** the first teachings about Christ, we
> **should go on** to maturity, not again **laying** a foundation of:
>
> - repentance from dead works
> - faith in God
> - instruction about baptisms
> - laying on of hands
> - resurrection of the dead
> - and judgement eternal.

Note that these six "basic/first" teachings are all nouns and adjectives with no verbs.  I have highlighted the verbs in the above translation.

Comment: That actually makes coherent sense with the Greek I am currently learning, thanks Dottard!